# Download pdf files from external url's - Heroku, NodeJS, Angular 7

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to download multiple pdf files from external sources to my nodejs server (in Heroku) temporarily and upload it to AWS S3 bucket.

I have tried multiple methods all of which works fine in my local machine but not in Heroku Dyno NodeJS Server. I am unable to even create folder in Heroku. I guess due to limited permission.

**In Node**

1) using **var download = require('download-file')** (using this currently in below code)

2) axios

3) res.download()

### Download Files Code

```
const downloadFiles = async (unique_files) =>  {

  for (let index = 0; index < unique_files.length; index++) {
    let file_ext = unique_files[index].substr(unique_files[index].length - 4);
      if(file_ext == ".pdf") {
        await downloadzz(unique_files[index])
      }
  }

}

function downloadzz(link) {
  download(link, function(err){ 
    if (err) throw err
    console.log("DOWNLOAD Complete");

  });
}
```

### Upload Files Code

```
const uploadFiles = async (unique_files) =>  {

  for (let index = 0; index < unique_files.length; index++) {
    let file_ext = unique_files[index].substr(unique_files[index].length - 4);
      if(file_ext == ".pdf") {
        await uploadzz(unique_files[index])
      }
  }
}

function uploadzz(link) {
    fs.readFile(require('path').resolve(__dirname+'/../external-pdfs/', link.slice(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)), function (err, data) {

    params = {Bucket: pdfBucket, Key: link.slice(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1), Body: data, ACL: "public-read" };
    s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Failed Upload", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully uploaded data to bucket", data);
        }
    });

  });
}
```

I don't get any error but no folder seem to exist with a name **external-pdfs** on heroku server.

I am open for better solutions: for example, directly uploading file from external url to s3...
How can I in read file from a external url and directly upload to AWS S3 bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). Setting the ***responseType*** as `stream`, you can get the file data and pass it as the body. Here it's an example code to get the pdf from a URL and uploading its info directly to S3:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const axios = require('axios');

AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
const s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
const URL = "<YOUR_URL>";

const uploadPdfToS3 = async () => {
    try{
        const {data, headers} = await axios.get(URL, {responseType: 'stream'});
        // Create params for putObject call
        const objectParams = {
            Bucket: "<YOUR_BUCKET>", 
            Key: "<YOUR_KEY>", 
            ContentLength: headers['content-length'],
            Body: data
        };
        // Create object upload promise
        await s3.putObject(objectParams).promise();
    } catch(err){
        console.log("ERROR --->" + err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, we can use FileSaver library to save the pdf file from library.

Find the below sample code to do this way.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQLXy.png)